# Batch rename of files with similar names

Tags: linux, batch-file

I have a series of files named like such:

```
file 1.jpeg
file 2.jpeg
file 3.jpeg
...
file 40.jpeg
```

I would like remove the space from all of their filenames without having to individually do it. I know its possible using something like: file{1,40}.jpeg or something like that but i can't remember and I don't even know how to search for it.

Thanks!

EDIT: linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.google.es/search?q=shell+rename+similar+files+in+a+directory

The first result is http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150

*Using the perl **rename** command [...] we can also, for example, strip spaces from filenames with this:*

```
~$ rename 's/ //' *.jpeg
```

In other posts I've found this kind of commands that do not require perl:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr --delete ' '`; done
```

I've not tried any of them.